# Custom DataProvider Nattable

Tags: java, swt, dataprovider, nattable

I create nattable the following way. But I can get access to the cells only through getters and setters in my Student class. How else can I access cells? Should I create my own BodyDataProvider or use IDataProvider? If it is true, could someone give some examples of implementing such providers?

```
    final ColumnGroupModel columnGroupModel = new ColumnGroupModel();
    ColumnHeaderLayer columnHeaderLayer;
    String[] propertyNames = { "name", "groupNumber", "examName", "examMark" };

    Map<String, String> propertyToLabelMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    propertyToLabelMap.put("name", "Full Name");
    propertyToLabelMap.put("groupNumber", "Group");
    propertyToLabelMap.put("examName", "Name");
    propertyToLabelMap.put("examMark", "Mark");

    DefaultBodyDataProvider<Student> bodyDataProvider = new DefaultBodyDataProvider<Student>(students,
            propertyNames);

    ColumnGroupBodyLayerStack bodyLayer = new ColumnGroupBodyLayerStack(new DataLayer(bodyDataProvider),
            columnGroupModel);

    DefaultColumnHeaderDataProvider defaultColumnHeaderDataProvider = new DefaultColumnHeaderDataProvider(
            propertyNames, propertyToLabelMap);
    DefaultColumnHeaderDataLayer columnHeaderDataLayer = new DefaultColumnHeaderDataLayer(
            defaultColumnHeaderDataProvider);
    columnHeaderLayer = new ColumnHeaderLayer(columnHeaderDataLayer, bodyLayer, bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer());
    ColumnGroupHeaderLayer columnGroupHeaderLayer = new ColumnGroupHeaderLayer(columnHeaderLayer,
            bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer(), columnGroupModel);

    columnGroupHeaderLayer.addColumnsIndexesToGroup("Exams", 2, 3);
    columnGroupHeaderLayer.setGroupUnbreakable(2);

    final DefaultRowHeaderDataProvider rowHeaderDataProvider = new DefaultRowHeaderDataProvider(bodyDataProvider);
    DefaultRowHeaderDataLayer rowHeaderDataLayer = new DefaultRowHeaderDataLayer(rowHeaderDataProvider);
    ILayer rowHeaderLayer = new RowHeaderLayer(rowHeaderDataLayer, bodyLayer, bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer());

    final DefaultCornerDataProvider cornerDataProvider = new DefaultCornerDataProvider(
            defaultColumnHeaderDataProvider, rowHeaderDataProvider);
    DataLayer cornerDataLayer = new DataLayer(cornerDataProvider);
    ILayer cornerLayer = new CornerLayer(cornerDataLayer, rowHeaderLayer, columnGroupHeaderLayer);

    GridLayer gridLayer = new GridLayer(bodyLayer, columnGroupHeaderLayer, rowHeaderLayer, cornerLayer);

    NatTable table = new NatTable(shell, gridLayer, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered in your previous question [How do I fix NullPointerException and putting data into NatTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189536/how-do-i-fix-nullpointerexception-and-putting-data-into-nattable/50342819#50342819), this is explained in the [NatTable Getting Started Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html#dataaccess_dataproviding).

If you need some sample code try the [NatTable Examples Application](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=examples_application)

And from knowing your previous question, your data structure does not work in a table, as you have nested objects where the child objects are stored in an array. So this is more a tree and not a table.